# Laravel field to open stream

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I installed composer and downloaded the repository from github and I move all the files to `htdocs/laravel-master` directory and when I run `composer install` via `cmd` I got the following error

[image: Error Image]

Comment: Try to pass `--prefer-source`

Comment: also when i try this composer create-project laravel/laravel lara --prefer-dist the same error

Comment: @user2239044 it's because of your connection. Check your internet connection and try again.